# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 for JSONString to ArrayList<String> conversion

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I am trying to convert this following JSON String to ArrayList using GSON.

```
[{type=Email, currentStatus=Draft, id=55, createdAt=1408339109, createdBy=9, depth=minimal, folderId=409, name=First Email, permissions=fullControl, updatedAt=1408339787, updatedBy=9, htmlContent={type=StructuredHtmlContent}}, {type=Email, currentStatus=Draft, id=56, createdAt=1408365174, createdBy=9, depth=minimal, folderId=42, name=Untitled Email, permissions=fullControl, updatedAt=1408365174, updatedBy=9, htmlContent={type=StructuredHtmlContent}}, {type=Email, currentStatus=Draft, id=57, createdAt=1408369734, createdBy=9, depth=minimal, folderId=42, name=new email, permissions=fullControl, updatedAt=1408369734, updatedBy=9, htmlContent={type=StructuredHtmlContent}}]
```

I am doing something like this below

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Email>>(){}.getType();

List<Email> elist = gson.fromJson(response.body, type ); // code fails here

for ( Email email : elist){
    // do next steps.
}
```

Please help to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debug and check the contents of response.body, i think that will be the key. Post that here

Comment: Post your Email class as well

Comment: please post here response.body as well